# Problem installing electron on Linux/macOS

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

i need to create an app using Angular and Electron. This app should work on Windows/macOs and Linux.

I tried to run it on Windows and it worked. But when i try on macOS or Linux, it fails...

Here is the output when i run with `npm run electron` :

```
Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/index.js:9:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! open-terminal@0.0.0 electron: `ng build --base-href ./ && electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the open-terminal@0.0.0 electron script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

In my package.json i created `"electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron ."` to run my app.

I tried to delete and re install, but it failed..
I tried to reinstall with :  `sudo npm install electron --verbose`

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@3.0.10 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@3.0.10 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Could you edit you post to include the commands which generate the error messages, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build instructions for electron on linux, macOS and windows are different. To build for linux, as per the electron docs, follow these steps:

---

**1.** Make sure you have python 2.7.x installed on your system. You can check the version of python running on your os by running the command `python -V`.

**2.** Install nodejs. You can download the installer from [here.](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

**3.** Since you've not mentioned the version of linux you're running, I'm assuming you're running Ubuntu. Install the following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential clang libdbus-1-dev libgtk-3-dev \
                   libnotify-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgconf2-dev \
                   libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev \
                   libxss1 libnss3-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib curl \
                   gperf bison python-dbusmock
```

These were the very basic required steps to build electron on linux. You may need to install several other packages depending your system architecture, project dependencies etc.

---

For complete build instructions, follow the electron docs. Here I leave you with some links.

**1.** [Build Instructions for linux](https://electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-linux)

**2.** [Build Instructions for macOS](https://electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-macos)

**3.** [Build Instructions for windows](https://electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-windows)

Comment: Then follow the build instructions in the links. And update the question with more relevant info, like linux distribution, platform architecure, nodejs version etc.