# Not able to globally install electron on MacOS due to error

Tags: macos, electron

I'm getting an error while trying to globally install electron, I'm not sure why.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v19.0.9/electron-v19.0.9-darwin-ia32.zip
npm ERR!     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/node_modules/got/source/as-stream.js:35:24)
npm ERR!     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR!     at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/node_modules/got/source/get-response.js:22:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.handleResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:155:5)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:402:35)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/source/index.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:623:27)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:487:22)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem installing electron on Linux/macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393675/problem-installing-electron-on-linux-macos)

Comment: @Rob That does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Rob That user already has electron installed, I am looking to install electron, however I'm getting errors while running npm -g electron

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? The `darwin-ia32` asset does not exist, hence the 404 HTTP status code.

Comment: @snwflk I am running macOS Monterey Version 12.2.1

Comment: Huh, I can't figure out why npm would try that asset. Check Electron's [installation guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/installation#customization), maybe force the architecture like `npm install --arch=x64 electron`?

Comment: @snwflk thank you! After that command electron now runs with no issues. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I don't know, your npm tries to install Electron with the `ia32` architecture, resulting in a downloadable zip file which is not provided by the Electron maintainers. That's why you're getting a 404 HTTP status code.

Going back in Electron's [releases page](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases), I cannot seem to find any `darwin-ia32` assets (darwin is the codeame for macOS).

You can try forcing npm to install the appropriate architecture using

```
npm install --arch=x64 electron
```

as suggested in Electron's [installation guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/installation#customization).